# É possível criar interfaces gráficas para aplicações em Python?

Tags: python, gui

E além disto, usá-las em um computador que não tenha um interpretador do Python? Se a resposta for sim, quais softwares são capazes de fazer isto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim é possível, você precisa de uma biblioteca que faça isto. Tem diversas opções dependendo da sua necessidade. Algumas opções (tem várias outras):

- [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)
- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)
- [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)
- [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)

Para executar aplicações Python sem instalar o interpretador a solução mais interessante é a criação de um executável. Algumas opções:

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) - Windows
- [pyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) - Multi plataforma
- [py2app](http://undefined.org/python/py2app.html) - MacOS

Nem todos funcionam com a versão 3.

Conhece o [Mercurial](https://mercurial.selenic.com/)? Esta é uma aplicação criada com Python usando GUI sem precisar do interpretador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Importante notar que tantoe sses criadores de .exe, quanto essa necessidade de ter a aplicaçlão + interpretador auto-contidos são necessidades do Windows. 

Ok - aplicações mobile tem necessidade semelhante - e aí você deve olahr o qPython e Kivy se quiser fazer algo para Android, por exemplo.

Mas em Linux e Mac OS, o Python funciona de forma modular - e criar um pacote Python instalável com PIP é a forma mais tranquila de  criar aplicações facilmente distribuíveis e reutilizáveis: nem o Python nem as dependências são duplicados para a instalação do programa

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta!

Comment: Sabe me informar qual a melhor para "modelagem" 3d?

Comment: Acho que nenhuma delas, que formam feitas pra aplicações comuns. mas pode ser que tenha algumas funções de 3D, as origens de algumas delas tem, mas não saberia dizer qual a melhor, ou o que melhor quer dizer. Só usei a Qt.