# Licenciamento de programas feitos em Python

Tags: python, licença

Por ser uma linguagem de programação aberta, qualquer software criado a partir dele será aberto? Ou também é possível o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais fechados?

Answer (score 3):

Do ponto de vista legal, você pode fazer como quiser, o software é seu e ninguém pode dizer nada como você vai distribuí-lo. A única restrição é se você usar códigos na sua aplicação que obrigue distribuí-la de forma aberta, mas nada tem a ver com a linguagem.

O termo usado "linguagem de programação aberta" está equivocado, isto não existe. A implementação da linguagem tem código aberto. E o código que você produz fica exposto, só isto.

Do ponto de vista técnico, a linguagem não ajuda proteger o código. Existem técnicas de ofuscação de código que ajudam. Não faz parte do foco desta pergunta mas citei alguns em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74770/101). Existem outros.

Não sei se entendi, mas se você está querendo desenvolver um sistema operacional com Python, você está em um caminho muito errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).